# Publish org entries to Jekyll with a custom header

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

I would like to generate a blog by publishing org files to jekyll, as described in the [wiki](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-jekyll.html).

The wiki recommends formatting each post like this:

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
---
layout: default
title: Benighted on the Ben.
excerpt: An unplanned bivouac on Ben Nevis.
---
#+END_HTML
It was early January when six of us travelled up to ....
```

While this works, it is inconvenient when exporting to other formats.  I am looking for a function (possibly a publish or preamble) that allows me to publish this

```
#+LAYOUT: default
#+TITLE: Benighted on the Ben.
#+EXCEPRT: An unplanned bivouac on Ben Nevis.

It was early January when six of us travelled up to ....
```

Into this

```
---
layout: default
title: Benighted on the Ben.
excerpt: An unplanned bivouac on Ben Nevis.
---
<p>It was early January when six of us travelled up to ....</p>
```

Has anyone accomplished this?  Does anyone know of a good place to start?

Answer (score 1):

I have written two org-mode exporter for pelican and hexo for my self (no public release yet, just opensource on GitHub)

In your case, the best way is write a org-mode exporter based on ox-html, I don't know if anyone did it for jekyll but you can based on my org-hexo to achieved this.

link:

https://github.com/coldnew/org-hexo

https://github.com/coldnew/org-pelican

Answer (score 0):

As strictly defining in the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-HTML-tags.html) there are several methods how to quote literal code. I've tested this one and it works fine in Org-mode 9.0.4

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html                                                                                                            
---                                                                                                                            
layout: post                                                                                                                   
title: Write Python programs                                                                                                   
tagline: " by means of Emacs' toolbox"                                                                                         
permalink: /coding/codewars-toy-tasks.html                                                                                     
categories: [literate programming, Python, CodeWars, emacs]                                                                    
tags: [coding, algorithms, org-mode-9, practice, TDD]                                                                          
---                                                                                                                            
#+END_EXPORT
```